# How do you guarantee a crawlspace with Go Deeper/Mom’s Shovel/Ehwaz?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-repentance

According to the [recent patch notes](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/250900/view/3117060130395071360),

> We Need to Go Deeper/Mom’s Shovel/Ehwaz now feature a secret method to guarantee a crawlspace once per floor and no longer create them based on random chance

What is the "secret method"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135006/discussion-on-question-by-blueraja-danny-pflughoeft-how-do-you-guarantee-a-cra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search for weird/unusual patterns on the floor and then dig there.

These are some examples:
(in order: Basement, Caves, Sheol, Womb, Cathedral, Chest)

[image]

Womb is probably the easiest place where to find them, due to the red palette. While in Flooded Caves is nearly impossible to distinguish patterns underwater.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUI6Z0uNjnc) for reference.